# How do I set a ref when using react.createElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get a ref to the component represented by the element i create, but cannot get it to work. I tried this:

```
            var comp = React.createElement(
                MyComp,
                {
                    props: myprops,
                    ref: "mycomp"
                }
            );
```

But this doesn't work. How do i set a ref on it so the parent can call `this.refs.mycomp.someMethod()`?

Comment: I think your code works fine. Can you give more context ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement
>
> ```
> ReactElement createElement(
>   string/ReactClass type,
>   [object props],
>   [children ...]
> )
> ```

The second parameter of the function is an optional props object for the component. Unless you want to refer to the props in the component as `props.props` you can splat the `myProps` object:

```
var comp = React.createElement(MyComp, { ...myprops, ref: "mycomp" });
```

```js
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.initialValue = props.initialValue;
    this.state = { value: this.initialValue };
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
  }
  
  increment() {
    this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1 });
  }
  
  reset() {
    this.setState({ value: this.initialValue });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="child">
        <h1>Counter: {this.state.value}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
  }
  
  reset() {
    this.refs.mycomp.reset();
  }
  
  render() {
    const myProps = { initialValue: 1 };
    const Comp = React.createElement(MyComp, { ...myProps, ref: "mycomp" });
    return (
      <div className="parent">
        {Comp}
        <button onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button> Calls this.refs.mycomp.reset
      </div>
    );
  }
}

  
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #555;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: #888;
  padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: why should i flatten them out? what's the reasoning?

Comment: You don't have to. I just find it less verbose to refer to `props.something` rather than `props.props.something`. Also wasn't sure if that was an issue or not  without seeing the `MyComp` component.

Comment: Since `this.refs` is deprecated from `react>=16.3`, what would its alternative to like `callback refs`.

Answer (score 6):

As of react v16.3, this.refs has been discouraged. One of the popular ways of doing it would be,

```
  const Comp = React.createElement(
                MyComp,
                {
                    props: myprops,
                    ref: ref => this.mycomp = ref
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Also can use `React.createRef` in `react>=16.3`, like this:

```
    class ParentClass extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
        // createRef here
        this.mycomp = React.createRef()
      }
    
      handleClick() {
        console.log(this.mycomp.current)
      }
    
      render() {
        const mycompProps = { something: '' }
        const mycomp = React.createElement(MyComp, { ...mycompProps, ref: this.mycomp })
    
        return <div onClick={this.handleClick}>This is Parant. {mycomp}</div>
      }
    }
```